# setting margins in chapter titles (University class file causing issue?)

Tags: margins, geometry

This is just my second large LaTex document so I'm still learning. And sorry if this is a duplicate, but I've tried to apply different solutions from various questions and I still need help overcoming the margins the class file seems to set for chapter titles. 
The final correction they asked me to do is make this title an inverse pyramid. Ideally something like this:

Analyzing spatiotemporal distribution of

uniquely fluorescent nanoparticles

in xenograft tumors

In the MWE below you'll see I tried to force line breaks, but it doesn't want to put more words on the top line (even though it should have room). The Chicago.clo and uuthesis2e.cls can be found here ([ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/uuthesis/new-2016-05-03/sample-thesis-0/](http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/uuthesis/new-2016-05-03/sample-thesis-0/))

```
\documentclass[11pt,Chicago]{uuthesis2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in,margin=1.25in]{geometry}
% also tried this, but didn't work either
%\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
%       \begin{list}{}{%
%               \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
%               \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
%               \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
%               \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
%               \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
%               \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
%           }%
%           \item[]}{\end{list}}

\begin{document}



\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm}
%\begin{changemargin}{-3em}{-3em}

\chapter[Analyzing spatiotemporal distribution of uniquely fluorescent nanoparticles in xenograft tumors]{Analyzing spatiotemporal distribution of\\ uniquely fluorescent nanoparticles\\ in xenograft tumors}\label{chap3}




\noindent \lipsum[1]

\restoregeometry
%\end{changemargin}

\end{document}
```

If I need to modify the class file, I may need some help knowing where it is defining margins for the chapter titles. I don't understand it well enough to have found it yet.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your chapter title is to wide to be placed page width ... so the solution can be to use smaller fonts in this particular title. For example: `\chapter[Analyzing spatiotemporal distribution 
         of uniquely fluorescent nanoparticles in xenograft tumors]
        {\huge
         Analyzing spatiotemporal distribution of\\ uniquely fluorescent nanoparticles\\ in xenograft tumors}\label{chap3}`. I tested with `book` document class.

Comment: Unfortunately, the thesis office won't allow a smaller font. Not sure I understand your comment completely, but I don't need the entire title to fit within the page width. I just need "Analyzing spatiotemporal distribution of" to fit on the top line. It should fit with narrow 1 cm margins or even 1.25 in margins. I just can't figure out where the class file is setting the margin for the chapter title (because it does work with other class files like `book`) and I can't overcome it with the geometry package.

Answer (score 3):

Found the part in the class file that was limiting the chapter heading width.
From what I gather, changing class files is discouraged, but this was a last resort ;)

I changed

```
\def\mainheadingwidth{4.5in}
```

to

```
\def\mainheadingwidth{5.4in} %minimum needed to get "distribution" on the top line
```

and got an inverted pyramid shape for my title that the thesis office wanted and didn't need to change any margins with the geometry package.

Here would be the new MWE that works for what I wanted:

```
\documentclass[11pt,Chicago]{uuthesis2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Analyzing spatiotemporal distribution of uniquely fluorescent nanoparticles in xenograft tumors}

\noindent \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```